# in python how ton plot a lorenz curve?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, statistics

it seems that my graph isn't right, but i don't know where my mistake
is

```
F = [0,0.577732, 0.934668, 0.947704, 0.969366, 0.986732]

percent = [0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0]
lorenz = [0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0]
plt.plot(percent, lorenz, '-o')
plt.title("Perfect price Distribution")


plt.figure(figsize = (9, 5))
plt.plot(percent, lorenz, '-o', label = 'Lorenz Curve')
plt.plot(percent, F, '-o', label = 'USA')
plt.title("The Difference between Perfect and Actual Wealth Equality")
plt.legend(loc = 'best', frameon = False)
```

[image: my plot]

Comment: You plotted the given values. If you plotted the same values manually on graph paper, you would get a similar plot. What were you expecting? Where did you get the values for `F`? They are quite different from the expected values.

Comment: i expected the orange line position on the other side of the blue one

Comment: Well, in that case you need to put other values for `F`.

Answer (score 1):

As @JohanC pointed out in his comment, the plots are in accordance with the values you have given. However, when I tried to recreate this with your code, I noticed that some markers or the line segments seemed to be a bit off. This becomes especially apparent when you draw grid lines with plt.grid().
If that is your concern, then you can try to use the cairo backend in matplotlib

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use( "cairo" )
```

You need to have the [pycairo](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pycairo) module installed. This produced lines that are plotted at the exact positions of the markers and dont seem to be off. The problem is known and the solution was proposed for example [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/11836) and in the linked issues therein. I dont know whether there are any current intentions to fix this in the default backend.